Need for a class encapsulation of main()
Since main() is made static for accessing it by JVM for not having an instance of its encapsulating class, then what is the need for encapsulating it?

You don't in recent versions of java.

what do you mean by "encapsulating class"? Do you mean that the method must be inside a class, as stated in the Java Language Specification? Maybe to not have different class file formats...  (As Sören probably meant, they are working on it {still preview feature} JEP 495: Simple Source Files and Instance Main Methods)

It is just that everything has to be in a class. As mentioned above the preview feature described in JEP 495 relaxes that. The JEP document introduction goes in to details.

Note there can be many main() entrypoints in the classpath so you need to qualify the one to launch (either by source file / class in command line or as MainClass for launchable jars) and that doesn't really change even with JEP495 as you still need to know the containing java file or class name.

As @Sören said, until the recent versions, it was just assumed that everything needs to be inside of a class, even the entry point of a program (maybe for injecting further dependencies inside the class). That is because Java is a purely object-oriented language (at least it was).
Now, you can write your main without actually defining any class. This happened since Java 21.
void main() {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
}

The runtime would compile and automatically create a class around it, based on the name of the .java file containing the method. Assuming that your file is called Runner.java, you could compile & run your code like this:
javac --source 21 --enable-preview Runner.java
java --source 21 --enable-preview Runner

... also enabling Java 21's preview features.
This version allows you to define the main logic without even creating a method.
System.out.println("Hello, World!");

inside a Runner.java file would be translated by the JVM as:
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}

You could also completely omit the compilation command by running your single-source program like this:
java --source 21 --enable-preview Runner.java


Note that --release n --enable-preview will only work with the corresponding Java version n (for example, you cannot use Java 23 compiler with --release 21 --enable-preview)
